# Filter by My Territories in Wave Analytics

Tags: analytics, einstein-analytics

Native Salesforce reports have a very easy dropdown to filter to My Accounts, My Territories Accounts, All Accounts.

The only filter I'm seeing in Wave at the moment is specifying which territory to show (with no logic about what territories the Current User is assigned to).

Am I missing an obvious setting in Wave or is this more complicated?